# Number of ways a set of nucleotides can be arranged (example from textbook)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, intuition

In the book: "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis" by John Rice, Example K in chapter 1, Rice writes:

[image: nucleotide_problem]

What does dividing the letters into subgroups do in this case? Isn't this question just asking how many ways you can rearrange the nine letters? What's the intuition behind dividing them into groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this question just asking how many ways you can rearrange the nine letters? **Yes**

What's the intuition behind dividing them into groups? Since the order within the group doesn't matter, diving into groups let you pick, where to put the 2's, the 3's and the 4's, and in how many forms, which is the goal in this case.

Comment: The order of the nucleotides does matter.  The author is choosing positions for identical nucleotides.

Comment: I know 2, 3, and 4 are the number of identical letters but why are we splitting them into these sizes specifically?

Comment: @Checklist So you pick the positions where to put the letters.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Right. What I said is that the order doesn't matter inside the group.

Comment: I guess I'm just missing a lot of background knowledge for this, Rice just calls this Proposition C but is there a name for this so I can read more about it elsewhere?

Comment: @Checklist  This is a [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Comment: @Checklist Say positions 1, 2, ..., 9 are split into three groups A = {5,7}, G={1, 2, 4, 9} and C = {3, 6, 8}. Then this is equivalent to the sequence G G C G A C A C G.